# IE6 CSS Z-index

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-6, z-index

I have a a list of image swatches when on mouseover a div popup should appear above all content. However I am finding that in IE6 that the div popup is sitting behind the elements that are generated after the popup. It is sitting correctly ontop of elements rendered before the popup.

A rough idea of what I have:

```
<ul>
     <li>
         <a href="#"><img src="image path to swatch"></a>
        <div class="tooltip">TOOLTIP POPUP</div>
     </li>
     <li>
         <a href="#"><img src="image path to swatch"></a>
         <div class="tooltip">TOOLTIP POPUP</div>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

I have quite a few of these ULs stacked on the page.

Rough idea of the CSS

```
 ul li {
       width: 150px;
       height: 20px;
       position: relative;
 }
 div.tooltip {
       width: 300px;
       height: 300px;
       position: absolute;
       top: -20px;
       left: -20px;
       z-index: 1000;
       display: none;
 }
```

I have tried making the parent li have a z-index of -1 and position relative, but this also hides the swatch. The swatches are generated dynamically and I need the individual tooltips to be positioned near the swatch itself, which is why I structured it inside a list.

I have also tried to increase the z-index using javascript when the swatch is hovered over so that it is the highest above all else, but this hasn't worked either. Eg:

```
 $('ul li').hoverIntent(
       function(){
    $('div.tooltip', this).css('z-index', '9000');
    $('div.tooltip', this).stop(true,true).show();
},
function() {
    $('div.tooltip', this).hide();
    $('div.tooltip', this).css('z-index', '1000');
});
```

Running out of ideas, so if anyone could help please? Thanks.

The code can be seen on JS Fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/melon/nUTgB/13/

Comment: I know this kind of sidesteps your question, so please forgive me, but it is time to let go of IE6. You'll feel so much happier when you forget that it ever existed.

Comment: Less than 9% of the _whole world_ still use IE6, most of them corporations whose employees won't even see your site due to access restrictions. I agree with Nacimota,  drop IE6 support.

Comment: I wish I could!!! But not allowed to unfortunately :(

Comment: From the code you published, it is not obvious when and how should be the particular `div.tooltip` displayed (is always has `display: none` now). Could you please send a link to jsfiddle demo that actually works in modern browsers as expected?

Comment: Im using the hoverIntent jQuery plugin but this is essentially the same as the the native hover function, this is where the show and hide function is called. The JS Fiddle link can be found here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/melon/nUTgB/13/) Also updated the post

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks The largest part of that percentage are users in China, and partly South Korea, Japan and India. The IE6 share in the western world is about 3 to 4%.

Answer (score 0):

To fix a lot of IE z-index bugs, keep this rule in mind:

`If something has a position attribute, it always needs a z-index`

That has helped me a lot with browser testing. That means that the LI tags need a `z-index: 1` set, because they have the `position:relative` attribute

Comment: I've tried that but it seemed to ignore it for elements rendered after a tooltip

Comment: What happens if you add position:relative and z-index:1 to the UL elements?

Comment: The swatches rendered after the currently hovered swatch is still appearing over the tool tip, additionally now any text rendered outside of the list is appearing ontop of the tooltip now.

Answer (score 0):

ie6 work on position relative more than absolute

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10280332/1312610